# scrollspy and change color don't work bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with scrollspy and a problem with the button that should appear on the navbar if you open with the phone or if you shrink the browser and i have problem with color in navbar

HTML

```
   <header id="header" class="fixed-top  align-items-center ">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-grey" id="navbar-example2">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logoimg" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"
                        style="width: 30%;"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">Home1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">Services</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Compétences</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading5">Tarifs</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading6">À Propos</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading7">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-example2" data-bs-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example"
            tabindex="0">
    </header>
```

CSS

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
}
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;

  position: relative;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header nav.navbar {
  z-index: 999;
}

header nav.navbar .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}


.logoimg {
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}

.logoimg:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

nav .navbar-nav li a{
  color: white ;
  }

.nav-item::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #03e9f4;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.nav-item:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  color: #03e9f4;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #03e9f4;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #03e9f4;
}

.dropdown-item.active,
.dropdown-item:active {
  color: #03e9f4;
}

.dropdown-item:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
}

.navtext:hover {
  color: #03e9f4;
}







.map-container-6 {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}

.map-container-6 iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.login-box {
  padding: 40px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.login-box h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-box .user-box {
  position: relative;
}

.login-box .user-box input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.login-box .user-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.login-box .user-box input:focus~label,
.login-box .user-box input:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-box .user-box textarea:focus~label,
.login-box .user-box textarea:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-box form a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-top: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px
}

.login-box a:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
    0 0 25px #03e9f4,
    0 0 50px #03e9f4,
    0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.login-box a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .25s
}

@keyframes btn-anim2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .5s
}

@keyframes btn-anim3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .75s
}

@keyframes btn-anim4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}











/* .login-box1 {
    padding: 40px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border-radius: 10px;
  } */

.login-box1 h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-box1 .user-box {
  position: relative;
}

.login-box1 .user-box input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;

  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.login-box1 .user-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;

  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.login-box1 .user-box input:focus~label,
.login-box1 .user-box input:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;

}

.login-box1 .user-box textarea:focus~label,
.login-box1 .user-box textarea:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-box1 a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #03e9f4;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-top: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px
}

.login-box1 a:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
    0 0 25px #03e9f4,
    0 0 50px #03e9f4,
    0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.login-box1 a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.login-box1 a span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box1 a span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .25s
}

@keyframes btn-anim2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box1 a span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .5s
}

@keyframes btn-anim3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box1 a span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .75s
}

@keyframes btn-anim4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}

.carousel-item {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 790px;
}


.carousel-inner .carousel-item > img {
  -webkit-animation: thing 20s;
  -o-animation: thing 20s;
  animation: thing 20s; 
}
@keyframes thing {
  from {
     transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}


.animate-text { 
 visibility:hidden;  
}

.carousel-caption{
height: 50%;
}

/* effet machine à écrire + animation CSS (SPECIAL) */
/*
.animate-text span { 
 display:inline-block;
  color:purple; 
  animation:fade-in 0.8s ease-in-out 1;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
 0% { opacity:0; font-size:0; xxmargin-left:100px; }
  100% { opacity:1; xxfont-size:300%; xxtransform:rotate(360deg); margin-left:0; }
}
*/

.bg-grey{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  
}
.bg-grey ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}

.bg-grey ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  color:red;
}

.blue{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

JS

````
```

 $(".menu-activator").on("click", function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  });

  "use strict";
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  animate_text();
});

// -------------------
function animate_text() 
{
  let delay = 100,
      delay_start = 0,
      contents,
      letters;

  document.querySelectorAll(".animate-text").forEach(function (elem) {
    contents = elem.textContent.trim();
    elem.textContent = "";
    letters = contents.split("");
    elem.style.visibility = 'visible';

    letters.forEach(function (letter, index_1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        // ---------
        // effet machine à écrire (SIMPLE)
        elem.textContent += letter;
        // ---------
        // OU :
        // effet machine à écrire + animation CSS (SPECIAL)
        /*
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = letter.replace(/ /,'&nbsp;');
        elem.appendChild(span);
*/
        // ---------
      }, delay_start + delay * index_1);
    });    
    delay_start += delay * letters.length;
  });
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* version jQuery */
/* ------------------------- */
/*
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {
  animate_text();
});
// -------------------
function animate_text() 
{
  let delay = 100,
      delay_start = 0,
      contents,
      letters;

  $(".animate-text").each(function(index, obj) {
    contents = $(obj).text().trim();
    $(obj).html(''); // on vide le contenu
    letters = contents.split("");
    $(letters).each(function(index_1, letter) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        // ---------
        // effet machine à écrire simple
        $(obj).html( $(obj).html() + letter ); // on ajoute chaque lettre l une après l autre
        // ---------
        // ---------
      }, delay_start + delay * index_1);
    });
    // le suivant démarre à la fin du précédent
    delay_start += delay * letters.length;
  });
}
*/


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 300) {
          $(".bg-grey").css("background" , "blue");
        }
  
        else{
            $(".bg-grey").css("background" , "green");   
        }
    })
  })

 ```
````

the problem i have with the scrollspy is that when i go down it doesn't change the color depending on where i am. I still have another problem it's with the responsiveness, I use bootstrap 5 I would like that when we open with the phone or when we shrink the screen that the navbar appears the menu button but it doesn't does not appear, I do not understand why. And I also have a problem in localhost the navbar changes colors but when it is put online it does not work I would like to know why.
In this link you can see result http://portfoliotest1.liveblog365.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the .navbar-toggler button has a transparent background-color and that's why it doesn't appear.
The color change of the splitter can be done using javascript and with the pixels returned by the scrollTop function.

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marvin90/gx149fzn/117)

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll === 0) {
  $(".bg-grey").css("background", "transparent");
} else if (scroll > 0 && scroll < 300) {
  $(".bg-grey").css("background", "blue");
} else if (scroll > 300 && scroll < 600) {
  $(".bg-grey").css("background", "green");
} else if (scroll > 600 && scroll < 900) {
  $(".bg-grey").css("background", "gray");
} else if (scroll > 900 && scroll < 1000) {
  $(".bg-grey").css("background", "purple");
}
```

Comment: Add at the end of your css this class to make the navigation button appear:
.navbar-toggler{
       background color: red !important;
       z-index: 9999;
}

Comment: thanks for your help but I have change how you talk but error doesn't leave check this link http://portfoliotest1.liveblog365.com you can see result.

Comment: Steps followed to get scrollspy working:
1-  Add a body element with the following attribute: data-bs-spy="scroll".
2- Add the class: nav-pills to the ul element of the nav.
3- Overwrote the classes: nav-pills and nav-link.active , to give the proper styles when the navigation element is active. See result: https://jsfiddle.net/marvin90/gx149fzn/113/

Comment: Steps followed to show button in mobile view:
1- Add the navbar-light class to the nav element
2-Overwrote the navbar-toggler class with the following styles: background-color: yellowgreen !important; z-index: 9999;
See result: https://jsfiddle.net/marvin90/gx149fzn/117/

Comment: This helped me solve the problem:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/scrollspy/#scrollspyHeading3

Comment: Also noticed that sometimes a blue color appears in the nav element and I fixed it by removing the .blue class from the html